# Can't run the module flask in python

Tags: python

I've been trying to run a code from the internet but I get this error that says:

in 
from flask import Flask
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'

This is supposed to be a referrence to something i need to work with and i don't know how to fix this as it's not my code.

Here's the link to the code where i got it from:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-simple-blockchain-using-python/

I just need to run it once so that i could get working on my stuff too.

Edit: i use the basic idle from python btw...

Comment: You don't have flask installed in your dev. env.

Comment: You will need to develop your question further, but from what i understood, you just dont have the module installed in you computer. Being that module Flask. A web app library. So what you need to do is basically dowload it

Comment: that's right i didn't download any external module, thanks i'll try to download it

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you dont have flask installed in your dev environment. Do
`pip install Flask`
or
`pip3 install Flask`
to install flask

Comment: they show an error, i tried to run them in cmd